# bokeh serve does not respond

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I try to run [the button](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#single-module-format) bokeh server example from the doc but nothing shows, i.e. the browser keeps turning indefinitely. Here is my command line:

```
http_proxy=  https_proxy=  bokeh serve test_button.py --port 26453 --log-level debug --host opit020.vm.cfm.fr:26453
```

As you can see, I:

- tried to deactivate proxies
- changed the port
- added logs
- tried on several hosts

but everything failed so far (`--show` option fails the same way on localhost). When I ping `http://myhost:26453/test_button`, the logs still show:

```
2017-04-28 16:19:40,580 [pid 8425] 0 clients connected
2017-04-28 16:19:40,580 [pid 8425]   /test_button has 0 sessions with 0 unused
2017-04-28 16:19:55,579 [pid 8425] 0 clients connected
2017-04-28 16:19:55,580 [pid 8425]   /test_button has 0 sessions with 0 unused
```

and nothing appears in my browser (locally or remotely).
When I hit `http://myhost:26453/test_button/ws`, I get:

```
2017-04-28 16:20:08,949 400 GET /test_button/ws (10.75.21.109) 0.77ms
2017-04-28 16:20:08,950 Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".
```

which proves the server is successfully reached (locally or remotely once again). There is another proof of life when I hit the root `http://myhost:26453/` (even if the browser keeps turning indefinitely as well):

```
2017-04-28 16:30:51,241 302 GET / (10.75.21.109) 0.47ms
```

Can you think of other things I could try to get this simple example work?

P.S. I use python 2.7 and bokeh 0.12.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Bokeh incompatibility with the new Tornado v4.5 release. You should pin your tornado version to the previous release (v4.4.2).

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6152